# Simplification of the boolean expression

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Simplify the following expressions to the simplest expression using De Morgan's theorem and Boolean algebra.

AB+(C+B')(AB+C')

=AB+ABC+CC'+ABB'+B'C'

=AB+CC'+A+B'C'

=A+CC'+B'C'

=A+B'C'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake between the second and the third line: $B\overline{B}$ is a contradiction, and hence $A B \overline{B}$ can be dropped (the same for $C \overline{C}$).

\begin{align}
 AB+(C+\overline{B})(AB+\overline{C}) &= AB+ABC+C\overline{C}+AB\overline{B}+\overline{B}\,\overline{C} \\
 &= AB + ABC + \overline{B}\,\overline{C} \\
 &= AB +  \overline{B}\, \overline{C}
\end{align}

Comment: Can I ask the reason of the downvote?

Comment: Thanks a lot!This was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

> Is the given solution correct?

No. In the second to third line you substitute $\rm ABB'$ with $\rm A$.

However $\rm ABB' = 0$ . ($\rm BB'$ is a contradiction.)

The rest of your working is okay.   So correct the error, try again, and you should have it.

Comment: Thanks a lot!This was very helpful!